# pandas time-weighted average groupby in panel data

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, weighted-average

Hi I have a panel data set looks like

```
stock    date     time   spread1  weight  spread2 
VOD      01-01    9:05    0.01    0.03     ...
VOD      01-01    9.12    0.03    0.05     ...
VOD      01-01   10.04    0.02    0.30     ...
VOD      01-02   11.04    0.02    0.05
...       ...     ...     ....     ...
BAT      01-01   0.05     0.04    0.03
BAT      01-01   0.07     0.05    0.03
BAT      01-01   0.10     0.06    0.04
```

I want to calculate the weighted average of `spread1` for each stock in each day. I can break the solution into several steps. i.e. I can apply `groupby` and `agg` function to get the sum of spread1*weight for each stock in each day in dataframe1, and then calculate the sum of weight for each stock in each day in dataframe2. After that `merge` two data sets and get weighted average for spread1.

My question is is there any simple way to calculate weighted average of spread1 here ? I also have spread2, spread3 and spread4. So I want to write as fewer code as possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need to `transform` the result back to the original, but using `.transform` with output that depends on two columns is tricky. We write our own function, where we pass the series of spread `s` and the original DataFrame `df` so we can also use the weights:

```
import numpy as np

def weighted_avg(s, df):
    return np.average(s, weights=df.loc[df.index.isin(s.index), 'weight'])

df['spread1_avg'] = df.groupby(['stock', 'date']).spread1.transform(weighted_avg, df)
```

#### Output:

```
  stock   date   time  spread1  weight  spread1_avg
0   VOD  01-01   9:05     0.01    0.03     0.020526
1   VOD  01-01   9.12     0.03    0.05     0.020526
2   VOD  01-01  10.04     0.02    0.30     0.020526
3   VOD  01-02  11.04     0.02    0.05     0.020000
4   BAT  01-01   0.05     0.04    0.03     0.051000
5   BAT  01-01   0.07     0.05    0.03     0.051000
6   BAT  01-01   0.10     0.06    0.04     0.051000
```

---

If needed for multiple columns:

```
gp = df.groupby(['stock', 'date'])
for col in [f'spread{i}' for i in range(1,5)]:
    df[f'{col}_avg'] = gp[col].transform(weighted_avg, df)
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't need to transform back and one want value per stock-date:

```
def my_avg2(gp):
    avg = np.average(gp.filter(like='spread'), weights=gp.weight, axis=0)
    return pd.Series(avg, index=[col for col in gp.columns if col.startswith('spread')])    

### Create some dummy data
df['spread2'] = df.spread1+1
df['spread3'] = df.spread1+12.1
df['spread4'] = df.spread1+1.13

df.groupby(['stock', 'date'])[['weight'] + [f'spread{i}' for i in range(1,5)]].apply(my_avg2)

#              spread1   spread2    spread3   spread4
#stock date                                          
#BAT   01-01  0.051000  1.051000  12.151000  1.181000
#VOD   01-01  0.020526  1.020526  12.120526  1.150526
#      01-02  0.020000  1.020000  12.120000  1.150000
```

Comment: Thank you  @ALollz